# Classification problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have this question in the assignment and I just don't know how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Are you doing a maximum likelihood classification?  If so, you could try to calculate the three likelihoods

Comment: @Henry I am confused with the two x values provided. How we will calculate the three likelihood

Comment: Please type you question instead of postings images.  Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  It you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are asked to find the most likely class of $x$, or in other words, to perform Maximum Likelihood Estimation.
For any $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, by applying [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Simple_form_2), we have that
$$\begin{align}\mathbb P(Y=i\mid X=x) &=\frac{f_{X\mid Y=i}(x) \times \mathbb P(Y=i)}{f_X(x)} \\
&= \frac{f_{X\mid Y=i}(x) }{3\times f_X(x)}\\
&\propto f_{X\mid Y=i}(x)\end{align}$$
We do not need to explicitly compute the terms whose value are independent of the value of $Y$.
Now, we know that conditional on $Y = i$, $X$ follows a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) with mean $\mu_i$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma_i$. The conditional density of $X\mid Y=i$ is thus
$$f_{X\mid Y=i}(x) = \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_i)^T\Sigma_i^{-1}(x-\mu)\right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^2|\Sigma_i|}} $$
To classify $x$, you have to pick the class $i$ that maximizes $\mathbb P(Y=i\mid X=x) $.
We see that it is equivalent to choosing the class $i$ that maximizes $f_{X\mid Y=i}(x) $, so now you have all the elements you need to classify $x$.

Comment: so for maximizing the fX/Y we need to classify for each of the Y=1,2,3. I am taking machine learning for the first time.Also this question is from Kevin Murphy book Exercise 4.22 QDA with 3 classes

Comment: Compute $f_{X\mid Y = i}(x)$ for each $i \in \{1,2,3\}$, and then pick the class $i$ for which it is the highest